# How to read set of files with different filenames into databricks notebook from blob storage

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to read all the Personal_details_info files into databricks notebook to process the data which are stored in the blob storage.

Personal_detail_Info_20220908000234
Personal_detail_Info_20220907000023
Personal_detail_Info_20220906000356

Customer_details_Info_20220908000342
Customer_details_Info_20220907000324
Customer_details_Info_20220906000123

Comment: What is the file format?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read Personal_details_info file.  Please follow this
syntax :

You can check your file location:

[image: Ref1]

**Code:**

Use `*` at the end of `Personal_detail_Info_*` file location.

```
df = spark.read.option("header",True).format("csv").load(f"/<Your_file_loaction>/Personal_detail_Info_*").csv")
display(df)
```

[image]